# Getting Points of Interest with Bing Maps SDK for Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, bing-maps

So I've recent installed and use the Bing Maps SDK for Windows 8.1, obtained as the extension to Visual Studio 2013: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/224eb93a-ebc4-46ba-9be7-90ee777ad9e1

There are a few samples for this SDK, but I am unable to find any that demonstrates how to get points of interest near or around a location or address.  For example, "restaurants near (address here)" or "restaurants near" (location).  Now I know there are some samples that does this using the REST or SOAP API.  However, I'm interested in doing this directly with the SDK.  Maybe through the "SearchManager"?  I haven't been able to find much information.  Does anyone know some references or could provide some tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get point of interest data into a native (C#, VB, or C++) app you can use the NAVTEQ POI data sources in the Bing Spatial Data Services:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478189.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585126.aspx

I wrote a free ebook on creating Location Intelligent Windows Store apps. Chapter 6 has a walk through of how to do exactly what you are looking for. You can download a free copy of the book here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/my-book/

You can also find all the code samples for the book here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Location-Intelligence-for-1c691d0e

Comment: Thanks for you information. I noticed in your code and references you're using REST service (through http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/ ).  Is this the only way?  Does the SDK not provide a more "native" way to perform this?  For example, more native is
var options = new Bing.Maps.Search.GeocodeRequestOptions(SearchInput.Text); 
                    var geocodeResult = await MyMap.SearchManager.GeocodeAsync(options);

Comment: The SDK does not wrap the REST services for POI data. The Search Manager only supports geocoding and reverse geocoding at this time. The search manager is just some code wrapped around the REST services. There are the old SOAP Search services, but we generally recommend using them as they are really slow and a legacy service that's mainly online for customers who haven't yet migrated off of it.